# Adding Struts2 Filters Causes Blank Page

Tags: java, jsp, maven, tomcat, struts2

I'm attempting to get a basic Struts2 application (using tomcat, building with maven) up and running. Tomcat and Maven are both working correctly; the page is served normally until I add some Struts filters into my web.xml (located at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF). Here's the code for my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app>

    <display-name>app</display-name>
    <description>tagline</description>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Additionally, here is the code for my struts.xml (located at src/main/resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="app" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

My catalina.log has the following error messages:

```
12-Jan-2014 15:33:20.256 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-16] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error filterStart
12-Jan-2014 15:33:20.256 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-16] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/app] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I've just noticed another issue present in catalina.log that only shows upon starting up tomcat:

```
13-Jan-2014 20:19:57.465 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init An incompatible version 1.1.27 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.29
```

The really weird thing is that the tomcat-native.tar.gz in my apache-tomcat-ver/bin is version 1.1.29.

Additionally, my localhost.log has a mess of errors:

```
13-Jan-2014 20:20:04.780 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter struts2
 Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC10/webapps/symIOsis/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5274)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:699)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1763)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC10/webapps/symIOsis/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer class:org.apache.struts2.components.PortletUrlRenderer - bean - jar:file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC10/webapps/symIOsis/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/portlet/PortletMode
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:235)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.portlet.PortletMode
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1286)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1128)
        ... 27 more
```

To me this looks like a dependency issue, however struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.java exists in that location. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Edit: I've also added the struts2-portlet-plugin as a maven dependency in hopes that it would resolve the problem. No avail, the same errors are still appearing.

Also, here's the requested pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-portlet-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.16</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: only dependency needed for using struts2 is the struts2-core one (org.apache.struts|struts2-core|2.3.16). You could also use a tomcat-maven-plugin for local testing (org.apache.tomcat.maven|tomcat6-maven-plugin|2.2) and then use mvn tomcat:run on your project location. Otherwise there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your web.xml or your struts.xml and they are in the correct place according to what you post (if there is an index.jsp at src/main/webapp) . Full stacktrace + pom would be handy to see.

Comment: If your app server is tomcat, why do you need portlet plugin?

Comment: Are you writing a portlet? Show the code example.

Comment: I've included the full stack trace. I'm not writing a portlet, I'm just trying to get the default tomcat/struts up and running.

Comment: Remove the plugins you're not using. You can't magically run a portlet in a non-portlet container, like the exception insinuates. It also ships with running applications.

Comment: I get the same errors whether or not I include all struts plugins or only the required ones. The running applications work fine, further adding to my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much headache and plenty of circles, I seem to have figured out the issue. Apparently, when building with maven, I do not need to copy the .jars from the distributed struts-ver/lib into my WEB-INF/lib folder. It's always something simple, eh?